# How would I change this small snippet so it works with oreg_replace

Tags: php, arrays, preg-replace

How  would I change this small snippet so that it works with preg_replace instead?

```
$words = array("bad1", "bad2", "bad3"); // bad words
$replacement = array("@#$@#", "good2", "b***3"); //however you want to censor 
$string = $_POST['joke']; // inputed string
$cleanstring = str_ireplace($words, $replacement, $string); //clean it up changed to ireplace removing case sensitivity.
echo($cleanstring); //echo it out.
```

I've tried **preg_replace(/$words/i, ** but with no luck. I also want to have some kind of if statement that sets a variable to either yes or no.

If any part of $string needed replacing set the variable to yes, if it didn't need any replacing set it to no.

But I'm still trying to think of how to go about that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`$cleanstring = preg_replace("/$words/", $replacement, $string);`

If you use double quotes a simple / on either side of $words will work, if you use  single quotes you should format it `'/'.$words.'/'` Just be sure to use the quotes, as the / modifier is required.